# Watermark a video programmatically

Tags: php, linux, video-encoding, watermark, html5-video

So I am looking for a way to watermark videos uploaded to my site programmatically.  I have looked at ffmpeg-php however this will not work as I am using shared linux hosting.  I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way that I can programmatically add a watermark to mp4 videos kind of how you do with the GD lib in php.

Has anyone successfully done this or does anyone know of a utility that will work on shared hosting?

Comment: If you have very of this to do I sort of have a feeling that shared hosting won't meet your needs very long. If you do think that your volume will be low enough that shared hosting can still support you, it probably wouldn't be to much burden to do the processing offline and then upload the watermarked video to the site later.

Comment: I don't think GD can handle video.

Comment: @jeffremb we plan to get a few of our own servers however since we are just starting out we wanted to minimize cost until some money came in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to do this on shared hosting unless they provided ffmpepg support. Ffmpeg would also have to be compile with vhooks enabled and the watermark.so library.

Comment: is ffmpeg the only solution you are aware of?  Do you know how youtube does theirs?

Comment: no there are other alternatives, however I can't imagine any of them are available on a shared host. Encoding videos takes a lot of cpu power. FFmpeg would be the easiest root.